# how todo work Expess4 with bodyParser urlencoded ( Postman ) and bodyParser json (curl) same time

Tags: express

I have this code on my server with express4:

```
// configure the app to use bodyParser()
/*app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));*/

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

When I comment the first bloc i can send data with:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{  "firstname" : "Frodo",  "lastname" : "Baggins" }' http://localhost:3000/accounts
```

and it's work well, but when i send firstname and lastname fileds with Postman with x-www-form-urlencoded and data in the body , does not work.

But if i enable the code again with:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Postman works well, but not curl.

There is a way to both methods work together ? so i can use angular2 instead curl by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain the body parsers like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

It will then detect which one to use.

Comment: nice, it works !! but have not read in any book or tutorial that ! where to find all those tricks?

Comment: @stackdave - This used to be default behavior, but they never said they could be chained when they changed the constructors. So you just have to know, or ask on StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 0):

Important to notice that if you use

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

The body parser has to be like this to work

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```